# what reference should I put inside Button void OnClick() in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I start to play , it can't jump to the next scene .It also pumps out many error ,one error repeats many times , Coroutine couldn't be started because the the game object 'FadeOut' is inactive!It made me confused since the rawimage is all black and must be inactive before the function onclick.
[image]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class ToLoading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button toLoad;
    public RawImage fadeOut;
    public Text loading;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()  //need to SetActive(false); ? if I set it false already in unity
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        ButtonClicked();
    }
    public void ButtonClicked() // 
    {
        fadeOut.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        loading.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(ToNextScene());


    }

    //going to do: fade out> 2 secoonds > to next scene
    private IEnumerator ToNextScene()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneForMovingAround");

    }
}
```

My question is : Should I put this script ToLoading to the fadeout rawimage ,or create an empty gameobject then put the script to it .Also , how to solve the problem -fade out error.And last , will it a problem about the code of scene part ?all of your help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you dont want to call buttonclicked every frame.. so dont put it in update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ButtonClicked()` method is executed every frame, which causes the unwanted behaviour your describe.

Remove the entire `Update()` method with its body from your file and run your game again.

Add `gameObject.SetActive(false);` to your `ButtonClicked()` method to deactivate the button upon clicking.

If you have attached the `ButtonClicked()` method to the `OnClick()` event in the inspector as you show in your screenshot then it should work as you would expect.

Comment: why can't I put the method within `void Update()` and that cause error ??

Comment: Because the `Update()` method is executed every frame. It might be a good idea to watch a tutorial explaining the basics of how Unity works regarding writing your own scripts.